# How to stop this variable outputting oddly in two places?

Tags: php

I'm working on some PHP that creates a table from a database, and this one section is stumping me, the table heading and footer echoes perfectly fine, but the rows get split up, the contents inside the  get put outside the table, but the  gets put correctly inside:

Here's what it looks like:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8xgD.png]

```
            $STH = $DBH->query($query_complete);

            // Perform the query
            $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $row = $STH->fetch();

            // Initialize our variables used for row counts, etc.
            $i = 0;
            $prevRowHour = 25; // Start at 25th hour as nothing will match this first-up.       

            $rowCount = $STH->rowCount();
            if($rowCount==0) {
                echo 'There are no results for this time frame.';
            }
            else {  

                // Create our table heading
echo <<<EOD
                <table class="tablesorter" id="trendTable">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Hour added</th>
                            <th>Case Number</th>
                            <th>Device</th>
                            <th>Component</th>
                            <th>Tier</th>
                            <th>Resolved</th>
                            <th>Exact Time Added</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
EOD;
                // Save the output into a variable to output after the sort order div
                while($row = $STH->fetch()) {

                    // Check if this hour matches the last.
                    if ($prevRowHour != $row['hour'] ) {
                        // If it doesn't -> Create new row

                        // Then make our fresh row
/* ~~~THIS LINE OUTPUTS WEIRDLY~~~ */           echo '<tr colspan="7">'.$row['hour'].'</tr>'; // THIS OUTPUTS ALL WEIRDLY
                    }

                    // Either way, we add a new row.


                    $prevRowHour = $row['hour'];
                    $i++;
                }
                echo <<<EOD
                    </tbody>
                </table><!-- end of trendTable -->
EOD;

            }
```

The line that appears to be having the issue is:

```
/* THIS LINE OUTPUTS WEIRDLY */         echo '<tr colspan="7">'.$row['hour'].'</tr>'; // THIS OUTPUTS ALL WEIRDLY
```

Here is the section of HTML this segment has been outputting (Tested in Chrome, Safari and FireFox on OS X) according to the element inspector:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGUmF.png

Yet in the view-source: it displays properly:

```
..<tbody><tr colspan="7">13</tr><tr colspan="7">11</tr><tr colspan="7">10</tr>..
```

I've removed all javascript and disabled it to confirm that it's not an outside issue. It occurs when there is no css/nojs and is pure HTML from the PHP.

I also switched out all the echo'd EOD to a regular single-line string.

**Has anybody ever seen anything like this before, and possibly know how to stop it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have any `<td>` elements. Contents of a table that are not in a cell will be rendered above the table. I think you meant `<tr><td colspan="7">`

Comment: You are a legend. I spent hours trying to figure this out and completely skimmed over the <td>.